# Do we need Axiom of Regularity to prove that $a=\{x,\{x\}\}\text{ is an ordinal }\implies x=\emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

> A set is an ordinal if it's transitive and well-ordered with respect to $\in$.

1. I found that $\emptyset$ is very special and that $\emptyset\in \mathbb N$. Is it correct that $a\text{ is an ordinal }\implies\emptyset\in a$?
2. Do we need Axiom of Regularity to prove that $a=\{x,\{x\}\}\text{ is an ordinal }\implies\text{ x}=\emptyset$?

Here is my attempt for 2nd question:

> It's clear that $a$ is well-ordered in respect to $\in$. $a$ is transitive set $\iff x\subsetneq a$ and $\{x\}\subsetneq a\iff  x\subsetneq a$ and $x\in a\iff  x\subsetneq a$.
>
> If $x=\emptyset\implies x\subsetneq a\implies a$ is transitive set. (satisfied)
>
> If $x\neq\emptyset\implies x\in x$ or $\{x\}\in x$. To make this case impossible to happen, we must appeal to Axiom of Regularity.

Comment: @EricWofsey, In my definition: a set is an ordinal if it's transitive and well-ordered with respect to $\in$. I will added this definition to my post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both questions is no.  For the first question, notice that $\emptyset$ is an ordinal.

For the second question, note that if $a=\{x,\{x\}\}$ well-ordered by $\in$, it has a least element $y$ with respect to $\in$.  Then $z\not\in y$ for all $z\in a$.  But since $a$ is transitive, every element of $y$ is in $a$, so $y$ cannot have any elements and so $y=\emptyset$.  Since $\{x\}$ is not empty, we must have $y=x$ and thus $x=\emptyset$.

(This argument shows more generally that any *nonempty* ordinal must have $\emptyset$ as an element.  We need $a$ to be nonempty to get the existence of a least element $y$.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I got your point. From your solution, I figure another way to do this: It's clear that $x$ is the least element of $a$ under $\in$. If $x\neq\emptyset$, then $\exists t\in x$. Hence $t\in x\in a$ by the transitivity of $a$. This contradicts the minimality of $x$. Thus $x=\emptyset$.